# Allow user to choose header style

Tags: php, theme-customizer, headers

I am working on developing a simple WP theme that our office will use as a starting point for any future projects that come in. My question is this: How would I go about adding functionality that would allow for the user to select from several different pre-built header styles using the native WP Customizer panel? I have seen similar functionality in several popular themes (Linstar, BeTheme, etc.) in their Theme Options panel, and I know that they have created multiple header.php files (header-1.php, header-2.php, etc.), but I was wondering if and how this might be accomplished using the WP Customizer panel. Any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

Do you want this to be an option per page? Or side wide.

If first, look into this: https://www.advancedcustomfields.com/
If second, look into this: https://blog.templatetoaster.com/wordpress-settings-api-creating-theme-options/